# How to bind the wrapper class data into custom objects fields and display it in pageblocktable

Tags: apex, visualforce, rest-api, wrapper-class

I have created REST which fetching the data from pardot and displaying it on the vf page. It is working fine. But I need to store this data in the custom object's corresponding fields on the vf page. As of now I bind the wrapper class on the page.

Suppose, I have FirstName and LastName fields in the wrapper class which I need to store in the First_Name__c and Last_Name__c fields on the custom object from wrapper class.

Here is my REST class:

```
{{
       wrapper = (PardotProspectWrapper)JSON.deserialize(res.getBody(), PardotProspectWrapper.class);
      system.debug('******Wrapper*****'+wrapper); // getting response here

        //iterating wrapper response and adding to Pardot_Prospect__c object
        List<Pardot_Prospect__c> csbs = new List<Pardot_Prospect__c>();
        for (PardotProspectWrapper w : wrapper) { // Error - Loop must iterate over collection: PardotProspectWrapper
            csbs.add(w.csb);
        }
        insert csbs;      
    }    



//wrapper created for custom object Pardot_Prospect__c
public class PardotProspectWrapper{
public Pardot_Prospect__c csb {get;set;}
public result result{get;set;}
public class result{
    public list<prospect> prospect{get;set;}
}
public class prospect{
    public String first_name{get;set;}
    public String last_name{get;set;}

}
 }
```

Can somebody please tell me how can I achieve it. it would be great help.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your wrapper has a confusing structure:

```
public class PardotProspectWrapper {

    public class result {
        public list<prospect> prospect{get;set;}
    }

    public class prospect {
        public String first_name {get;set;}
        public String last_name {get;set;}

    }

    public Pardot_Prospect__c csb {get;set;}
    public result result {get;set;}
}
```

because it has a property `csb` that is a single record yet a property `result` that can represent many records. Also just a list of `prospect` objects would be enough to represent the data (or indeed a list of `Pardot_Prospect__c`).

However, using the current wrapper classes this should work:

```
List<Pardot_Prospect__c> csbs = new List<Pardot_Prospect__c>();
for (PardotProspectWrapper.prospect p : wrapper.result) {
    csbs.add(new Pardot_Prospect__c(
        First_Name__c = p.first_name,
        Last_Name__c = p.last_name
    ));
}
insert csbs;
```